# New DBProject creation says Project type not available even though SSDT is installed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am trying to create a DB Project in Visual Studio 2013. I have installed SSDT Version 12.0.50730 . But when creating the db project it says project type is not supported by this version of application.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend installing the latest update for Visual Studio 2013: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx

And then performing a re-install SSDT using SSDTSetup.exe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx